# QMultilineElement not calling QEntryDidEndEditingElement: on delegate

Tags: quickdialog

I'm trying to use QuickDialog (github.com/escoz/QuickDialog) to make a tablew view showing some debug info, like the values of constants etc. Most of the values are long URLs so i can't use a QLabelElement. QMultilineElement seems to be perfect for this but i need to know when the user modify the text of the pushed text view and i can't figure out how to do it.

QMultilineElement has a delegate property but i can't get it to get called. Looking in the code it seems to me that that delegate only works with QLabelElement, is it true? what am i missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I ended up implementing this one, no? Can you confirm?